# Scam or OpenID support is canceled?

Tags: support, openid

I received following e-mail

> YOUR ACTION IS NEEDED
>   Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are ending support for third party OpenID providers. Your immediate action is needed in order for your account to stay active.
>
> Please click to add an email and password credential to your account.
>
> Alternately you can associate your account with Google or Facebook via the same link.
>
> OpenID will be no longer supported on July 25, 2018. If you haven’t updated your account before then you will lose access to your account.

I assume it is scam since links look fishy.

Please clarify situation

If it is scam I suggest to notify users on potential issue